# Turn Off Dictionary in Tess4J

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract-ocr

The accuracy of character recognition in my **tess4j** OCR application is very low. I have heard that **turning off the dictionary in tess4j** will increase the accuracy by letting individual characters to be recognized. But i don't know how to do it. Anyone know how to turn off the dictionary in **tess4j**?